# Does nested operators unsubscribe with the takeUntil?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Is the **takeUntil** will manage the subscription of the **mergeMap** when destroyed$ is emitted in the following code? In other words, is the mergeMap leak a subscription?

```
combineLatest([
    this.selectedCustomerId$.pipe(
        -->mergeMap<--(customerId => invoicesService.getInvoices(customerId)
    ),
    this.configuration$
]).pipe(
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
).subscribe([invoices, configuration] => this.displayInvoices(invoices, configuration));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there will be no memory leakage.

To understand that you need to understand how pipe works -
Without calling subscribe - there is no subscriptions, doesn't matter what operators you have put it, what `pipe` does, is it creates a new observable, which, while subscribing to, subscribe to the source observable, and while unsubscribing, it unsubscribe to the source observable.
Even though you have two pipes here - the "un-subscription" will bubble up. i.e. when destroyed$ emits the combine latest subscription will end, than, each of the combineLatest parameters subscription will end, than response of the pipe  in which you used the mergeMap will end, which means the return value of the mergeMap will end too.

I hope it wasn't too complicated of an explanation, the short version is that when using pipe everything is connected so when you unsubscribe it unsubscribes all sources.